# Reset back to factory setting after using EPPROM EPCS16

Tags: fpga

I am a newbie to FPGA world. I just leared and did the instruction to use the EPPROM EPCS16 to load the a different initial configuration for DE2 board of Altera. Now, I cannot get back to the initial point where I turn up the board and all LEDs, 7 segment LEDs and the rest will run as being checked in the factory. I need to reset it because i will return the board to my university.

Comment: You can't unless you still have or can find the original code. I suggest you ask your university what to do. They probably don't care but if it is a practicum, they might ask you not to leave your code on it. Also please use correct capitals in your question.

Comment: You should be able to get the code from the Altera web site.

Answer (score 1):

If you know how to load *.jic file in EPCS16, then the only thing you need is that file. You can find it on the [Terasic main page of your board](https://www.terasic.com.tw/cgi-bin/page/archive.pl?Language=English&CategoryNo=183&No=30&PartNo=4) where you should download CD-ROM and find the correct file.